# C++ error C2512 trying to use ifstream to read a file in a class, visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, constructor, ifstream

I admittedly am an extreme C++ novice, so please forgive me for my probably very naive question.

I am writing code that should parse an assembly language file in its fundamental parts, to be translated into machine language at a second stage.

I have built a `parser` class, but I am not having success in opening the external assembly `.asm` textfile, and in feeding it to the various functions that compose my `parser` class.

More in particular, there are problems with the constructor.
I attach the full code I wrote below:

```
// parses .asm assembly files
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <varargs.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class parser
{
private:
    istream inputfile;
    char inputname[30];
    string line;
    bool endfile;
    bool a_command, l_command, c_command; 
    string parsedLine, destParsedLine, compParsedLine, jumpParsedLine;
public:
    // default parser constructor
    parser()
    {
    }

    //parser(char* argv[])
    //{
    //  reader(argv[]);
    //}

    // opens input file
    string reader(char* argv[])
    {
        strcpy(inputname,argv[1]);
        strcat(inputname,".asm");
        // opens input .asm file
        ifstream inputfile(inputname);
        // reads first line
        getline(inputfile,line);
        if (line[0] == '/' || line.empty())
            inputfile.ignore(line.length(),'\n');
        return line;
    }

    // checks if at end file
    bool hasMoreCommands()
    {
        a_command = false;
        l_command = false;
        c_command = false;
        endfile = false;
        if (inputfile.eof())
            endfile = true;         
        return endfile;
    }

    // advances read of inputfile
    void advance()
    {
        if (line[0] == '/' || line.length() == 0)
            inputfile.ignore(line.length(),'\n');
        getline(inputfile,line);
    }

    /* function for labelling the type of command (address,computation,label) */
    bool commandType()
    {
        if (line[0] == '@')
            a_command = true;
        else if (line[0] == '(')
            l_command = true;
        else
            c_command = true;
        return a_command, l_command, c_command;
    }

    // function to select parsing function
    string selector()
    {
        if (a_command || l_command)
            symbol();
        else if (c_command)
        {
            dest();
            comp();
            jump();
            string parsedLine = destParsedLine + compParsedLine + jumpParsedLine;
        }
        return parsedLine;
    }

    // function returning address or label symbol
    string symbol()
    {
        if (a_command)
            string parsedLine = line.substr(1);
        else if (l_command)
            string parsedLine = line.substr(1,line.length()-1);
        return parsedLine;
    }

    // functions returning computation destination
    string dest()
    {
        size_t equal = line.find('='); //no '=' found = returns 'npos'
        string destParsedLine = line.substr(0,equal);
        return destParsedLine;
    }
    string comp()
    {
        size_t equal = line.find('=');
        size_t semicolon = line.find(';');
        string compParsedLine = line.substr(equal,semicolon);
        return compParsedLine;
    }
    string jump()
    {
        size_t semicolon = line.find(';');
        string jumpParsedLine = line.substr(semicolon);
        return jumpParsedLine;
    }
};

// main program
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bool endfile = false;
    string parsedLine;
    int count = 0;

    if ((argc != 2) || (strchr(argv[1],'.') != NULL))
    {
        cout << argv[0] << ": assembly .asm file argument should be supplied, without .asm extension\n";
        return 1;
    }

    parser attempt1 = parser();
    attempt1.reader(argv[]);
    while (!endfile)
    {
        attempt1.hasMoreCommands();
        if (endfile)
            return 0;
        if (count > 0)
            attempt1.advance();
        attempt1.commandType();
        attempt1.selector();
        cout << parsedLine << endl; //debugging purposes
        count++;
    }
}
```

I provide the name of the `.asm` textfile to be opened, from the command line (`.asm` file located in the same folder of this `cpp` file).

Hence I need to use `varargs.h` which I suppose may be part of the problem.

When I try to build this, visual studio 2008 gives me the following 2 errors:

> 1 error **C2512**: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>' : no appropriate default constructor available *line 21*
>
> 2 error **C2059**: syntax error : ']' *line 137*

Help appreciated, and insults tolerated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Remy Lebeau suggestions, the modified code below at least compiles correctly (still does not do what it is supposed to do though)

```
// parses .asm assembly files
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <varargs.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class parser
{
private:
    istream inputfile;
    char inputname[30];
    string line;
    bool endfile;
    bool a_command, l_command, c_command; 
    string parsedLine, destParsedLine, compParsedLine, jumpParsedLine;
public:
    // default parser constructor
    parser()
    {
    }

    // ignores inputfile line if comment or empty
    void ignoreline()
    {
        if (line[0] == '/' || line.empty())
            inputfile.ignore(line.length(),'\n');
    }

    // composes inputfile name and opens input file
    void reader(char* argv[])
    {
        strcpy(inputname,argv[1]);
        strcat(inputname,".asm");
        // opens input .asm file
        inputfile.open(inputname, fstream::in);
        // reads first line
        getline(inputfile,line);
        ignoreline();
    }

    // checks if at end file
    bool hasMoreCommands()
    {
        a_command = false;
        l_command = false;
        c_command = false;
        endfile = false;
        if (inputfile.eof())
            endfile = true;         
        return endfile;
    }

    // advances read of inputfile
    void advance()
    {
        ignoreline();
        getline(inputfile,line);
    }

    /* function for labelling the type of command (address,computation,label) */
    bool commandType()
    {
        if (line[0] == '@')
            a_command = true;
        else if (line[0] == '(')
            l_command = true;
        else
            c_command = true;
        return a_command, l_command, c_command;
    }

    // function to select parsing function
    string selector()
    {
        if (a_command || l_command)
            symbol();
        else if (c_command)
        {
            dest();
            comp();
            jump();
            string parsedLine = destParsedLine + compParsedLine + jumpParsedLine;
        }
        return parsedLine;
    }

    // function returning address or label symbol
    string symbol()
    {
        if (a_command)
            string parsedLine = line.substr(1);
        else if (l_command)
            string parsedLine = line.substr(1,line.length()-1);
        return parsedLine;
    }

    // functions returning computation destination
    string dest()
    {
        size_t equal = line.find('='); //no '=' found = returns 'npos'
        string destParsedLine = line.substr(0,equal);
        return destParsedLine;
    }

    string comp()
    {
        size_t equal = line.find('=');
        size_t semicolon = line.find(';');
        string compParsedLine = line.substr(equal,semicolon);
        return compParsedLine;
    }

    string jump()
    {
        size_t semicolon = line.find(';');
        string jumpParsedLine = line.substr(semicolon);
        return jumpParsedLine;
    }
};

// main program
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bool endfile = false;
    string parsedLine;
    int count = 0;

    if ((argc != 2) || (strchr(argv[1],'.') != NULL))
    {
         cout << argv[0] << ": assembly .asm file argument should be supplied, without .asm extension\n";
        return 1;
    }

    parser attempt1 = parser();
    attempt1.reader(argv);
    while (!endfile)
    {
        attempt1.hasMoreCommands();
        if (endfile)
            return 0;
        if (count > 0)
            attempt1.advance();
        attempt1.commandType();
        attempt1.selector();
        cout << parsedLine << endl;
        count++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class uses `std::istream` for the `inputfile` member, but does not initialize it. That will not work.

In this situation, your class would need to use `std::ifstream` instead for its `inputfile` member, and then call its `open()` method before trying to read from it.

Also, your `reader()` method is ignoring the `inputfile` member, instead creating a local variable of the same name to read from.  You need to get rid of that local variable, and instead call `open()` on your class member.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. How do I open my `inputfile` member in the declaration, considering I need to set up the `inputname` based on user command prompt input (`argv[1]`)? This is in part what `reader()` does.

Comment: @clumsybutwilling you don't have to open it in the declaration at all. You can declare it in the class header, let it default initialize in the constructor, and then call the public `open()` method on it in your `reader()` method